# Python stacktrace help

Tags: python, django, stack-trace

I have this stack trace error when I try view some data in my Python website, could some one clue me up as to what the problem is I am so lost

```
   Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://mywesbite.genericdomain.co.uk/admin/shop/passwordresetrequest/4/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'mywebsite.news',
 'mywebsite.store_locator',
 'mywebsite.css_switch',
 'mywebsite.professional',
 'mywebsite.contact',
 'mywebsite.shop',
 'tinymce',
 'captcha']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html, error at line 20
   Caught an exception while rendering: 'PasswordResetRequest' object has no attribute 'date'
   10 : 


   11 : {% block coltype %}{% if ordered_objects %}colMS{% else %}colM{% endif %}{% endblock %}


   12 : 


   13 : {% block bodyclass %}{{ opts.app_label }}-{{ opts.object_name.lower }} change-form{% endblock %}


   14 : 


   15 : {% block breadcrumbs %}{% if not is_popup %}


   16 : <div class="breadcrumbs">


   17 :      <a href="../../../">{% trans "Home" %}</a> &rsaquo;


   18 :      <a href="../../">{{ app_label|capfirst|escape }}</a> &rsaquo; 


   19 :      {% if has_change_permission %}<a href="../">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}{% endif %} &rsaquo; 


   20 :      {% if add %}{% trans "Add" %} {{ opts.verbose_name }}{% else %} {{ original|truncatewords:"18" }} {% endif %}


   21 : </div>


   22 : {% endif %}{% endblock %}


   23 : 


   24 : {% block content %}<div id="content-main">


   25 : {% block object-tools %}


   26 : {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}


   27 :   <ul class="object-tools"><li><a href="history/" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a></li>


   28 :   {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="../../../r/{{ content_type_id }}/{{ object_id }}/" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif%}


   29 :   </ul>


   30 : {% endif %}{% endif %}


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in root
  490.                 return self.model_page(request, *url.split('/', 2))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in model_page
  509.         return admin_obj(request, rest_of_url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in __call__
  1098.             return self.change_view(request, unquote(url))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in _commit_on_success
  240.                 res = func(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  873.         return self.render_change_form(request, context, change=True, obj=obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in render_change_form
  590.         ], context, context_instance=context_instance)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  108.     return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  178.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  71.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  97.         return compiled_parent.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  178.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  71.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  97.         return compiled_parent.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  178.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  71.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  243.                     return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  71.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  24.         result = self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  71.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  243.                     return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  71.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  244.             return self.nodelist_false.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  81.             raise wrapped

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/shop/passwordresetrequest/4/
Exception Value: Caught an exception while rendering: 'PasswordResetRequest' object has no attribute 'date'

Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 71, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 87, in render
    output = force_unicode(self.filter_expression.resolve(context))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 572, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 37, in _dec
    args[0] = force_unicode(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
    s = unicode(s)
  File "/var/www/mywesbite/src/mywebsite/../mywesbite/shop/models.py", line 1105, in __unicode__
    return ", ".join((str(self.account),self.date.strftime("%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p")))
AttributeError: 'PasswordResetRequest' object has no attribute 'date'
```

My model

```
class Account(BaseAccount):
    """
    The account is an extension of the Django user and serves as the profile
    object in user.get_profile() for shop purchases and sessions
    """
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    default_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='billing_account', blank=True, null=True)
    security_question = models.ForeignKey(SecurityQuestion)
    security_answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    how_heard = models.CharField("How did you hear about us?", max_length=100)
    feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
    opt_in = models.BooleanField("Subscribe to mailing list", help_text="Please tick here if you would like to receive updates from %s" % Site.objects.get_current().name)
    temporary = models.BooleanField()

    def has_placed_orders(self):
        """
        Returns True if the user has placed at least one order, False otherwise
        """
        return self.order_set.count() > 0

    def get_last_order(self):
        """
        Returns the latest order that this customer has placed. If no orders
        have been placed, then None is returned
        """
        try:
            return self.order_set.all().order_by('-date')[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def get_currency(self):
        """
        Get the currency for this customer. If global currencies are enabled
        (settings.ENABLE_GLOBAL_CURRENCIES) then this function will return
        the currency related to their default address, otherwise, it returns
        the site default
        """
        if settings.ENABLE_GLOBAL_CURRENCIES:
            return self.default_address.country.currency
        return Currency.get_default_currency()
    currency = property(get_currency)

    def get_gateway_currency(self):
        """
        Get the currency that an order will be put through protx with. If protx
        currencies are enabled (settings.ENABLE_PROTX_CURRENCIES), then the
        currency will be the same returned by get_currency, otherwise, the
        site default is used
        """
        if settings.ENABLE_PROTX_CURRENCIES and settings.ENABLE_GLOBAL_CURRENCIES:
            return self.currency
        return Currency.get_default_currency()
    gateway_currency = property(get_gateway_currency)


    def password_reset_presave(sender, **kwargs):
        """
        This pre-save is responsible for generating a unique key for the request
        before it is saved to DB.
        """
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        if not instance.key:
            instance.generate_key()

class PasswordResetRequest(models.Model):
    """
    Stores a history of all of the password reset requests that have been
    issued across the site. It is also used to validate resets against a given
    URL given the key.
    """
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    issued = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    used = models.BooleanField()

    def is_valid(self):
        """
        Is this password reset request still valid? Returns true if it hasn't
        yet been successfully used, and was issued any time within the last
        seven days
        """
        return not self.used and datetime.datetime.now() < self.issued + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

    def __unicode__(self):
        """
        The unicode representation of this password reset request. It is build
        using the unicode representation of the customers account, plus the
        date and time the request was made, in string form
        """
        return ", ".join((str(self.account),self.issued.strftime("%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p")))

    def generate_key(self):
        """
        Generate a uuid4 key and assign it to this objects key attribute
        """
        from uuid import uuid4
        self.key = uuid4()

    class Meta:
        """
        Django meta options

        verbose_name = "Password Reset Request"
        verbose_name_plural = "Password Reset Requests"
        """
        verbose_name = "Password Reset Request"
        verbose_name_plural = "Password Reset Requests"

pre_save.connect(password_reset_presave, sender=PasswordResetRequest)
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't contain the offending line from the stack trace... instead of `self.date.strftime()` from the stack trace, the only __unicode__ method in this code calls `self.issued.strftime()`. Have you edited the code since you encountered the error? Does the error still occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was no reference of date is should of been issued

Answer (score 5):

The significant piece is in the last few lines (remember that the most recent call, ie: the one that cause the error, is always printed last in a stacktrace):

```
  File "/var/www/mywesbite/src/mywebsite/../mywesbite/shop/models.py", line 1105, in     
  __unicode__
  return ", ".join((str(self.account),self.date.strftime("%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p")))
  AttributeError: 'PasswordResetRequest' object has no attribute 'date'
```

What this means is that, in the file `mywebsite/shop/models.py` on line 1105 (which is in your `def __unicode__(self):` method), you are calling `self.date.strftime()`, but the model has no property called `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the last line:

In

```
/var/www/mywesbite/src/mywebsite/../mywesbite/shop/models.py
```

in the `__unicode__` method you have a line:

```
return ", ".join((str(self.account),self.date.strftime("%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p")))
```

and that `self` don't know about the `date` attribute. Maybe there is none defined.
If you're unsure, change this particular return statement to return something meaningless but correct for the moment and see, if it was the only error.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is in the **unicode** method of the PasswordResetRequest model defined in shop/models.py. You try to access self.date on this object and it doesn't have a date attribute.

Maybe if you paste your model I could help more...